# transpose rows to columns in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query output as below

```
Customer policytype plan amount 

Sam      ulip       P1   250

Sam      ulife      u1   435

Sam      Ulip       P2   370

Hazar    Ulip       P1   679

Hazar    Ulife      u1   567
```

And so on ....

I need to transpose above output as follows

```
Customer ulip ulife

Sam      250  435

Sam      370  Null 

Hazar    679  567
```

Can someone help me to achieve above result in db2

Comment: can you explain what is the logic behind the transpose

Comment: I want to show individual ulip policy amounts under ulip column and individual ulife amount under ulife column customer wise. For example, in the above output, Sam has two ulip policies and one ulife policy. Hence there will be two rows for Sam showing ulip amount and ulife amount(in case if there is no amount show null for second row)

Comment: But how did you match ulip and ulife in first row what is the relation why not 370  instead of 250 in first row

Comment: Actually there is a column available called plan category which shows the plans under different categories. Sam has taken two different plans which falls under ulip and he has taken another plan which falls under ulife category. I need to show plans taken by customer wise under different categories rowwise for example, as per above example, Sam has taken two ulip and one ulife and hence I need to show two rows with category wise(one column) per category due to my requirement.

Comment: Can you add that column in sample data

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, do you have a link to where this is described in the documentation?

Comment: @Lennart - Strange, maybe not.  I can't find anything.  It's not even a reserved word!

Answer (score 4):

Use `conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT customer,
        Max(CASE WHEN policytype = 'ulip' THEN amount END) AS ulip,
        Max(CASE WHEN policytype = 'ulife' THEN amount END) AS ulife
FROM   Youratable
GROUP  BY customer,
            CASE WHEN plan IN ( 'p1', 'u1' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```